# shiny app functionality for prompting a user for inputs and assigning the inputs to variables

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have an app which dynamically sources one of the multiple .r files for performing transformations on data. In the files I currently have cat and readline commands to display / prompt user for input and accept users input through console. However, I would like to have a text output and text input box in the shiny UI where prompts are displayed in textoutput box and the sequential processing halts until user inputs a value and then proceeds for next user input.

Added one TextInput box and one TextOutput box and an action button. Added Render text in the files that sourced and also input$variable. However the code does not stop execution and does not print the text in text output box and wait for the user to enter input and press the action button.

```
Func_OP.AVISIT <- function(){
   observeEvent(input$button2, {
   output$value <- renderText('Enter AVISIT')
 })
# OP.AVISIT  <- readline(prompt="AVISIT is an assigned variable user input 
 expected: ")
 # })
OP.AVISIT  <- input$Variable
return(OP.AVISIT)
}
df$AVISIT  <- Func_OP.AVISIT()
```

72: observeEventHandler [C:\DataScience\Certara\Project\CertaraApp/app.R#195]

Comment: Maybe the [req](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/req.html) function from shiny will help you. It basically stops a function until a particular variable becomes available.

Comment: If you need to stop execution and wait for input, you probably need something like shiny modal dialogs (https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/modalDialog.html). For simple input, you can have a look also at shinyalert: https://github.com/daattali/shinyalert#examples

Comment: I wonder, why not ask the desired user Input before running the script?